# OpenCMIS TCK Basics Test Group never ends

Tags: cmis, opencmis, cmis-workbench

I have developed a CMIS server for a custom repository, and when I run TCK tests on it, `Root Folder Test` takes forever and I have never been able to wait until the end of it.

The blame is actually on `getObjectParents` implementation. When I put a breakpoint there, I realize that TCK tests have created too many documents on the root folder, and they keeps calling `getObjectParents` for each of them. It takes so long that I have never managed to wait till the end to see what happens next! I don't think there's an infinite loop firstly because any time I pause I do stop at my `getObjectParents` breakpoint and each time I get a different document id (at least about 50 of them that I managed to track).

Also as a P.S., if I intentionally break my implementation of `getObjectParents` and throw a `CmisRuntimeException`, TCK tests will run and pass Ok.

Any similar experience or solution is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is a TCK issue.

Have you checked how much time your getObjectParents implementation needs to respond for one document? 
Some clients call this method frequently. If it constantly takes too long (>2 sec), clients may not be able to work with your repository.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, it was just too many documents on my repository. So yes, nothing wrong on the server code :)